# Are external dependency's original sources get packed into the final apk if provided as a separate maven artifact?

Tags: android, apk

Suppose my Android app uses an external dependency (some `aar`), e.g.:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "some.lib:1.2.3"
}
```

The dep's `aar` itself has no sources packed into it, just bytecode. But there is also a separate `aar` file that contains only original source code in plain text and it is published along with the "main" `aar` at maven repo. In Android Studio, if I click a class represented by that lib I can see the original source code (vs decompilation). Nice.

Now the question: do the original source code gets packed into the final apk of my app? This is specifically for the case - when a dependency provides original sources as a separate maven artifact in addition to the main aar/jar contaning only byte code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge Maven source artifacts are optional and only for use within the development IDE so you don't have to decompile the byte code and also have the source code comments available including JavaDoc.

When you compile your app the source code AAR/JAR dependencies are simply ignored - the compiler only uses the artifact containing the byte code.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Robert! That would be my best guess, but I just wanted to get a confirmation. BTW, is there an official documentation on that (about the "source code AAR/JAR dependencies are simply ignored")?

Comment: @VitKhudenko The compiler can't do anything with the sources because it is just the sources without any Maven/Gradle or whatever build script. Let us just assume for a moment that Android compilers would integrate something from the source artifacts into an APK file. Most open source project artifacts are also available as source artifact so it would have to be very common to find elements from the source artifact in the final APK file. I have reversed a lot of APK files and never found anything that could be originated from a source APK.